# Getting python to seaarch for specific words in an input

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, text

I have been trying to create a basic program (to later incorporate into a bigger one) that searches for specific words within a user input, here is what I originally did:

```
command=input(">")
for "hi" in command():
    print("Hello there.")
```

I thought this would search for "hi" in the user input and if it found the word, it would say hi back, this did not work so I tried using variables instead:

```
command=input(">")
string = "hi"
for string in command():
    print("Hello there.")
```

This still did not work so I did both these again but used "if" instead of "for", and nothing had changed. If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated, thanks! - James.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `in` operator for membership checking:

```
if 'hi' in command:
    print("Hello there.")
```

Also Note that since `command` is a string and not a callable object you can not use parenthesis the the trailing of it.

And note that when you use `in` it checks the membership in the whole of the string and it's possible that you have another word in your text which is contains `hi` like `high`, that using `in` it will returns True which is not what you want.

So all you should do is splitting the string with whitespaces and check the membership of word `hi` within other words:

```
if 'hi' in command.split():
        print("Hello there.")
```

Comment: Ahh yes I knew it was simple, I just tried the for loop first and forgot to remove the brackets when changing it to "if", silly mistake, thanks!